# Is it correct to say $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[F_{X}(x)] = f_{X}(x)$ or $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[F_{X}] = f_{X}$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functions, notation

Is it correct to say $\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[F_{X}(x)] = f_{X}(x)$ or $\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[F_{X}] = f_{X}$?

This notation question comes up in probability, where $F_{X}$ is a CDF of a continuous PDF $f_{X}$.

My issue here is that $F_{X}(x)$ is a fixed value, rather than a function. Furthermore (correct me if I'm wrong), writing
$$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[F_{X}(x)] = f_{X}(x)\text{, }x \in \mathbb{R}$$
is confusing since $x$ is being treated as a variable and a constant in $\mathbb{R}$, so it may be more correct to write
$$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}[F_{X}(t)]\Large_{t = x} \normalsize  = f_{X}(x)\text{, }x \in \mathbb{R}\text{.}$$
I think I may be more comfortable just writing $$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[F_{X}] = f_{X}$$
but I don't think I've ever seen derivatives notated this way.

Comment: I'd use $F'$ instead and avoid dummy variables altogether. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation for other notational choices.

Comment: This is a matter of style, really: sometimes $F_X(x)$ means "the function $F_X$ where we use the name $x$ to refer to its single argument". Other times it means "the number given by evaluating $F_X$ at the number $x$". Both styles are used. The first style becomes more important with partial derivatives, because with partial derivatives, you have to disambiguate the argument with respect to which you are differentiating. If you don't name the arguments, then about all you can do is number them by their position, which can get very cumbersome very quickly.

Comment: This is to mention that the accepted answer does not correspond to universally accepted conventions and that it might even appear to condone some fallacious usage (whose disadvantages can be seen every day on this site, if I may add). Yes $F_X$ is a function and $F_X(x)$ is a number. A satisfying notation would be $$\frac{\mathrm dF_X}{\mathrm dx}(x)=f_X(x),$$ where $\mathrm d$ instead of $\partial$ indicates that $F_X$ is a function of a single variable hence one is really asserting that $$\left(F_X\right)'=f_X.$$

Comment: @Did Thanks Did.